# VB: Stored Procedures and Passing in Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am having a difficult time getting a stored procedure to execute with a parameter being passed into it. I have changed out the code with different examples from the web, but I keep getting the below error, so I must be ding something wrong.

```
*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Error' to data type int*
```

A job number is getting passed from txt_JobNumber.Text into v_jobNumber, and then it gets passed into the stored procedure. The stored procedure then does a lookup, and an insert. The stored procedure executes fine on its own in T-SQL “EXEC Z_Add_LotNumber 'IU9FU-0000'”

Below are some code snipped for the VB, Stored Procedure, and the Stack Trace. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong.

I am using visual Studio 2013 professional and SQL Server 2008 R2

## VB Code

```
Private Sub btn_Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Run.Click
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult

    v_jobNumber = txt_JobNumber.Text    'IUBG1-0000  >>> Value of txt_JobNumber.Text
    lbl_JobNumber.Text = v_jobNumber

    '======================================================================================================
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim com As SqlCommand
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=[hostname];uid=[user];pwd=[password];database=[database]"

    conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    com = New SqlCommand()

    com.Connection = conn
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    com.CommandText = "Z_Add_LotNumber"
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fjobno", v_jobNumber)   'IUBG1-0000  >>> Value of v_jobNumber

    conn.Open()
    com.ExecuteNonQuery() ‘<<<<< Error >>>>> [Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Error' to data type int.]
    conn.Close()
    '======================================================================================================

    response = MsgBox("Job Number: " & v_jobNumber)

End Sub
```

## Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Z_Add_LotNumber]
  @fjobno varchar(50)
AS
DECLARE @V_Date smalldatetime;
DECLARE @V_fpartno varchar(25);

SET @V_Date = GETDATE();
SET @V_fpartno = (SELECT fpartno FROM joitem WHERE fjobno =  @fjobno);

BEGIN
.
.
.
END

INSERT INTO Z_LotNumber(
        JobNumber
        PartNumber
        CreateDate
        .
        .
        .
        )Values(
        @fjobno
        @V_fpartno
        @V_Date
        .
        .
        .
        )
```

## Stack Trace

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at AutoGenLotNumber.Form1.btn_Run_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\xxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\AutoGenLotNumber\AutoGenLotNumber\Form1.vb:line 32
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at AutoGenLotNumber.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

## Table Definition

```
    COLUMN_NAME,                DATA_TYPE,          CHAR_MAX_LENGTH,    IS_NULLABLE
1   Id                          int                 NULL                NO
2   JobNumber                   char                15                  YES
3   PartNumber                  char                25                  YES
4   PartRev                     char                3                   YES
5   PartQuantity                numeric             NULL                YES
6   RecordType                  char                1                   YES
7   LotNumber                   char                20                  YES
8   CreateDate                  smalldatetime       NULL                YES
9   PartDescription             varchar            -1                   YES
10  HIBIC_Number                varchar             22                  YES
11  ExpirationDate              varchar             7                   YES
12  CIFF_Reference              varchar             300                 YES
13  Auxiliary_CIFF_Reference    varchar             300                 YES
```

Comment: Show `Z_LotNumber` table definition...

Comment: You dont have to concatenate single quote to parameters value.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter definition to this:

```
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fjobno", v_jobNumber)
```

Or my prefered way:

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fjobno", v_jobNumber))
```

EDIT:
You dont have to concatenate single quote to parameters value.

EDIT 2:

```
 conn.Open()
 com.ExecuteNonQuery() //Not ExecuteScalar()
 conn.Close()
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and I am still getting the same error. Is there of anything else I can try?

Comment: Also, you are using com.ExecuteScalar(), you use that method when you want to return a single value from your stored procedure, just try with ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: I swapped out the execution statement and I am still getting the same error on that line of code.